# Using python to measure Wi-Fi

Tags: python

I am working on a school project in which I must measure and log Wi-Fi (I know how to log the data, I just don't know the most efficient way to do it). I have tried using by using

```
subproject.check_output('iwconfig', stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

but that outputs bytes, which I really don't want to deal with (and I don't know how to, either, so if that is the only option, then can someone explain how to handle bytes). Is there any other way, maybe to get it in plain text? And please do not just give me the code I need, tell me how to do it.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you at any chance mean `subprocess`?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. I assume that you are using python 3.x. `iwconfig` is sending you text encoded in whatever character set your terminal uses. That encoding is available as `sys.stdin.encoding`. So just put it together to get a string. BTW, you want a command list instead of a string.

```
raw = subprocess.check_output(['iwconfig'],stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
data = raw.decode(sys.stdin.encoding)
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm!